# Reading Jenkins pipeline configuration files outside workspace

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have jenkins pipelines in a git repo called `jenkins-pipelines`. I have multiple jenkins instances **one per environment**. To keep **a single pipeline for all environments**, I externalized the environment specific variables for each pipeline in a folder called `config` within `jenkins-pipelines` git repo.

Here is a snippet that I use in my k8s pipeline to read the pipeline config. The problem is the pipeline config is not available in project workspace and I have to write the conditional snippet to guess and read the pipeline config file. Is there a better and straight forward way to address this problem?

```
     sh '''#!/bin/bash 
          if [ -d 'config' ]; then
            cat config/k8s.json 
          elif [ -d ../workspace@script ]; then
            cat ../workspace@script/config/k8s.json 
          elif [ -d ../${JOB_NAME}@script ]; then
            cat ../${JOB_NAME}@script/config/k8s.json
          fi
     '''
```

Example config in `jenkins-pipelines` repo k8s/config.json:

```
{
  "aws-env1": {
     "state": "blah"
  },
  "azure-env1": {
     "state": "blah2"
  }
}
```

Comment: What kind of config info do you keep? Does Jenkins run on k8s?

Comment: The config is primarily for the jenkins pipeline. I have several different environment on different cloud providers. I am keeping this environment specific values in the config files like the storage buckets info, metzdata for jenkins job,etc. jenkins does not run on k8s.

Comment: What king of config is it? Is it unique per app and env? Or just per env?

Comment: Updated question. It is one config per pipeline with all environment details.

Comment: Ok, so you have multiple Jenkins instances and each one uses the same pipelines but has different configuration. Is that correct? Do you care about having git history for that config?

Comment: Correct. I do not care about git history. I just need the latest pipeline config.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered setting up a [config file](https://plugins.jenkins.io/config-file-provider/) per Jenkins instance and then referencing that config from your pipeline?

For example you could define a config file called `pipeline-config` and then reference it from your pipeline as follows:

```
configFileProvider([configFile(fileId: 'pipeline-config', variable: 'myJsonConfig')]) 
        {
            sh "cat $myJsonConfig"
        }
```

This way the pipeline code is the same but each Jenkins has its own config that is easy to fetch.